# Gnome-session from ssh X returns "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication", but xterm works

Tags: gnome, headless, gnome-session

This is a new post from an previous question - someone said to use `gnome-session` vs. `startx`, but that gets 4

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication
```

and then quits. This is 18.04 ARM based for the client side (where I want to run `gnome-session`) and 18.04 x86 for the Server (with forwarding and all).

I am not sure what authentication it wants? I have verified the `.Xauthority` permissions and `xauth` list on both machines yields the same 2 magic cookies (10 and 11) and the `$DISPLAY` is 10.0. Obviously I have X11 forwarding enabled or `xterm` (and `xeyes` and `xedit` and so on would not work). So, something that `gnome-session` does is the issue. Also, I do not have a `~/.ssh/rc` file.

You can see I checked all of the queries on this error I could find.
So, I do not know how to find what is wrong with `gnome-session`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found that I can use **remote-desktop** but not with Gnome-session due to some bug in xrdb or gnome in Ubuntu 18.04. 
I can use xfce instead and it all works fine. I would hope that whatever bug is stopping gnome-session working is fixed eventually as I prefer it. 
I was not able to use remote X because GNOME has an issue where some parts want to use one scheme and some another in that case. Xrdb uses Xorg and that just works fine. I thought I could use Vino and VNC for this, but I do not know how to tell vino to launch the desktop - the instructions I was given segfault. There may be some other VNC which can work but all the instructions I see is from a few years ago, and all complaints about it not working applies to 18.04.
Obviously it would be nice if this were possible since Remote desktop is limiting as a client model.